# Creating lots of threads in Ruby crashes server?

Tags: ruby, linux, multithreading, bash

I have some servers that we run lots of stuff on. They're already under too much load often and are prone to crashing.

I have a Ruby program that is a wrapper for another Ruby program. The wrapper spawns a thread that runs the main Ruby script that calls another service which might take 10-20 seconds to return a response, so it's not actively processing.  It does this for each argument, so in the worst case it does 60 at a time.

I didn't think it would cause much of an issue because the threads were waiting on IO after all, but creating 60 threads that run the other Ruby script seem to be taking its toll, often timing out or hosing the server.  I guess there's some overhead there?  Maybe I didn't account for what Linux has to do internally for each bash and Ruby instance?

I would consider myself a linux newbie since a lot of the internals still are magic to me.  Could someone explain why my approach is stupid and would I be better off limiting myself to 10 threads or putting a second delay in my loop that creates the threads?  How much overhead is there in creating the bash environment to run an external command in Ruby?  Would I be better off creating the command with several commands in succession to reduce that overhead?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it really necessary to rely on shell scripts to accomplish those tasks? When possible it's better to integrate your logic as one whole Ruby script instead. And I mean that as the instance, not necessarily the script files included. Summoning more processes from external binaries makes things run heavy and slow. Even with shell scripting you try to avoid external binary tools when possible if the shell already has features that can provide similar solutions. By the way it's better if you ask this in Server Fault.

Comment: This is all hypothetical since we can't see what you're trying to do. Unless you show us code we have to imagine your code and what you're asking the system to do, and that's a lousy way to offer you advice. We have no idea how much memory your threads are going to consume, nor do we know how much the spawned processes are going to use.

Comment: This behavior might also depend on the threading implementation of the exact version of Linux and Ruby interpreter.